# nginx numeric subdomain return conflicting server name

Tags: nginx

Hi I am trying to configure a server and its subdomain with nginx but the nginx shows conflicting server name when I try to use only numbers for the subdomain. 
I have tried settings below they work for subdomain type one.mydomain.com  but return ignored conflicting server name error if I use the same for 1.mydomain.com

Any ideas why is that? Ubuntu 18.04 nginx 1.14.0
SSL includes subdomain in question too

```
    server {
        # SSL configuration
    #
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
        root /var/www/one;
        index index.html;
        server_name one.mydomain.com;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Try `nginx -T` to see your entire configuration. Is there another `server` block with a conflicting `server_name`?

Comment: then it shouldn't be OK for non numeric subdomain isn't it? anyway there is only one other config for the domain itself with server_name mydomain.com;

Comment: "conflicting server name" is caused by a duplicate `server_name` directive. `nginx -T` will allow you to identify where the duplicate is located.

Comment: I wish it would be that easy then I wouldn't need to post this question, what I am trying to say without changing anything else it works when I create a subdomain confing with server name one.mydomain.com but doesn't work for with 1.mydomain.com